# Can we combine two function in jquery with different event type

Tags: jquery, select, input, onchange, onkeyup

Is there anyway i can combine this :

```
$("tbody").on("keyup", "tr td:nth-child(2) input,td:nth-child(3) input,td:nth-child(4)",
function () {
    $(this) //input
    .closest("tr") //finds the row associated with the input
    .find("td:first input") //returns the first cell
    .val(this.value); //sets the text
});

$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first input").val( this.value );
});
```

to only one function for `select change` and `keyup for input` like:

```
$("tbody").on("input keyup select change", "tr td:nth-child(2) input,td:nth-child(3) input,td:nth-child(4)",
...
});
```

also i want to set it like the first input of `type=text` like :

`$(this).closest("tr").find("td:first input[type="text"]").val( this.value );`

but its not working.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("tbody").on("keyup change", "tr td:nth-child(2) input,td:nth-child(3) input,td:nth-child(4) select",
function () {
    $(this) //input
    .closest("tr") //finds the row associated with the input
    .find("td:first input") //returns the first cell
    .val(this.value); //sets the text
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/yvDDp/4/)**

Comment: wow, i think i tried  that combination before, but doesnt notices that was working. haha txt sir @Unknown

Comment: however i cant work it only on ther first input of type text. Can you help me on that

Comment: .find("td:first input['type=text']").val(this.value); this doesnt work

Comment: It should work. Is that working fine/still you are facing an issue?